# Deploying CDN Endpoints Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

When deploying my Terraform scripts I keep getting this error... I've tried all sorts in order to get this fixed but not having any luck so far.

Error: Error creating CDN Endpoint "brcgs-ngd-mig" (Profile "cdn-ngd-mig" / Resource Group "rg-ngd-mig-web-01"): cdn.EndpointsClient#Create: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="BadRequest" Message="HostName "https://ngdmigwebreact.z33.web.core.windows.net/*" is invalid. It must be a valid domain name, IP version 4, or IP version 6."

Here is my Endpoint Configuration:

```
resource "azurerm_cdn_endpoint" "brcgs-ngd-mig" {
  name                = "brcgs-ngd-${var.environment}"
  profile_name        = azurerm_cdn_profile.ngdmig.name
  location            = "Global"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  origin {
    name      = "BRCGS-Web"
    host_name = "https://ngdmigwebreact.z33.web.core.windows.net/"
  }
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The host_name should be "ngdmigwebreact.z33.web.core.windows.net".